# Trouble with Wix Integration in Node.js: Obtaining OAuth Tokens

Tags: node.js, express, velo

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on integrating Wix with my Node.js backend, and I have encountered some challenges regarding the OAuth token retrieval process. Here are the details of the issues I'm facing:

1. Objective:
   I am aiming to obtain the refresh and access tokens from Wix OAuth and store them in my SQL database using Sequelize.
2. Problem Description:
   I am unsure about the correct procedure for obtaining the OAuth tokens. Specifically how to get refresh and access token.
3. Code Snippet:
   Here's a snippet of my current implementation for token retrieval:

   ```js
   import axios from "axios";
   import catchAsyncError from "../middlewares/catchAsyncError.js";
   import dotenv from "dotenv";
   import WixToken from "../models/wixToken.js";
   import printStatement from "../utils/printStatement.js";
   dotenv.config();

   const clientID = process.env.WIX_CLIENT_ID;
   const clientSecret = process.env.WIX_CLIENT_SECRET;
   const redirectURI = "http://localhost:4000/auth/v1/redirect-url";

   export const wixGetCode = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
     const wixAuthUrl = `https://www.wix.com/installer/install?token=${req.query.token}&appId=${clientID}&redirectUrl=${redirectURI}`;
     res.redirect(wixAuthUrl);
   });

   export const wixgetToken = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
     const { code } = req.query;
     const response = await axios.post(
       "https://www.wixapis.com/oauth/access",
       {
         client_id: clientID,
         client_secret: clientSecret,
         grant_type: "authorization_code",
         code: code,
       },
       {
         headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
         },
       }
     );
     const { access_token, refresh_token } = response.data;
     const token = await WixToken.findAll()
     if (token.length === 1){
       if (token[0].token !== refresh_token) {
         await token[0].update({ token: refresh_token });
       }else{
         printStatement("Token is same as previous token");
       }
     }
     else{
       await WixToken.create({ token: refresh_token });
     }

     printStatement("Token saved successfully");
    
     res.redirect(
       `https://www.wix.com/installer/token-received?token=${response.data.access_token}`
     );
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Wix Integration with Node.js - OAuth Access and refresh Token Retrieval

Hello Stack Overflow community,

After some thorough investigation and experimentation, I have successfully resolved the issue I faced with Wix integration in Node.js, specifically regarding the OAuth token retrieval.

GitHub Repository:
To assist others who might be working on a similar integration, I have created a basic template for Wix integration with a Node.js server, utilizing MySQL and Sequelize. You can find the template on my GitHub repository:

[Wix Integration in node js](https://github.com/Saqib-Ansari786/wix-server-node.js)

Feel free to clone or fork the repository and adapt it to your specific needs. I hope this template proves helpful to the community.
Thank you to those who provided assistance and guidance during my troubleshooting process. If you have any further questions or improvements to suggest, feel free to comment on this answer.

I hope this solution and template are valuable to others encountering similar challenges. Happy coding!